# IOS app - can debug, but not release

Tags: ios, compilation, precompile

I've been trying to submit an app to the app store for a client (my first try) and have been running into various and sundry problems. I finally decided to create a new app name, recreate the developer provision profile and recreate the developers certificate.

I can now run it in simulator and debug on the device, but can no longer run it in release mode - it doesn't even compile. The error message is:

```
arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/me/Documents/iphone/QuizApp/CityGuide_Prefix.pch: No such file or directory
```

The reference to the "CityGuide_Prefix.pch" file would be a holdover from the app I based it on, and apparently did not rename correctly. I don't know why the problem showed up now.

At the beginning of the compile log there is a reference to this file:

```
ProcessPCH /var/folders/YN/YNuTu4omEDm9bUMfK4s5yU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/CityGuide_Prefix-etfgludtmplcfzcirudhxormhsna/CityGuide_Prefix.pch.gch CityGuide_Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
```

And it also shows up under the gcc compile command under this parameter:

```
-c /Users/me/Documents/iphone/QuizApp/CityGuide_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/YN/YNuTu4omEDm9bUMfK4s5yU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/CityGuide_Prefix-etfgludtmplcfzcirudhxormhsna/CityGuide_Prefix.pch.gch
```

My question is, how do get rid of this old reference? And why did it work before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the build settings for your target in release mode. You will find a GCC_PREFIX_HEADER directive stating the wrong precompiled header file name (CityGuide_Prefix.pch). Change it to the right value (which you can find inspecting the debug configuration).

If you don't find that directive for your target, check the general project build settings.

Alternatively, you can open your /project.pbxproj file and search for ".pch" (without quotes), in order to fix that value for the release configuration.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the Xcode settings, but it was right in project.pbxproj. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look into the Build Phases of your target and figure out the file is named there under Compile Sources. If so, remove it there.